# Embed Windows Media Player in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, media-player, media

I downloaded the source code from:
http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/using-windows-media-player-com-in-wpf/

I want to customize the play, buy add Play, Pause and Stop buttons to the form.

However I can't access the method: `axWmp.Ctlcontrols.play();`

> 'WMPLib.IWMPControls' does not contain a definition for 'play' and no extension method 'play' accepting a first argument of type 'WMPLib.IWMPControls' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

This would not happen if I add Windows Media Player under Windows Form .NET 2.0 Application. Is there any way to access the `.play()` and `.stop()` functions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a COM reference to Windows Media Player wmp.dll in your main project.